# Variable input not working, how to use user input for variable?

Tags: python, variables

My code:

```
birthYear = input("When were you born?")
thisYear = 2018
hippoSpan = 50
pabloSpan = 1881

print("You were born in " + str(birthYear) + " and currently it is 2018.")

print("")

print("You are " + str(thisYear - birthYear) + " years old.")
print("If you were a hippo, you would have " + str(hippoSpan - birthYear) + " years left to live.")
print("Pablo Picasso is " + str(pabloSpan - birthYear) + " years older than you.")
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I am trying to get user input to be in the variable, so what the user puts in as their `birthYear` then it can use that to subtract from `thisYear`. Please point out any mistakes.

Comment: You are probably using Python 3 where `input` returns a string. Does `birthYear = int(input("When were you born?")` fix everything?

Comment: yes, that fixes the issue. Thank you!